# How to access spring mvc properties value in websocket onopen event?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans, websocket

I am using `spring mvc + websocket`. I have created `application.properties` to store configuration data of project. Now I want to use that properties values in websockets `@onOpent()` event. I am able to access those properties in simple rest controller  `@RequestMapping()` but unfortunately I am not able to access those properties in in websockets `@onOpent()` event, I am getting `null` value for the same. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Websocket server class in not spring component.
you can mark websocket handler class as component using @Component annotation on class. Then you will be able to access properties. 
Hope this helps you.

Comment: its still giving me null value!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using Java websockets. you can use spring 4 websockets [here](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-websocket-sockjs-stomp-tomcat-example) is sample

Comment: Yes, I am using java websockets. _Spring 4 websockets_ was one of the option for me, but for some reason I had to choose _pure java websockets_ for my system and have to continue with the same.